# ReportLab - Handle position of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, linechart, reportlab

I am trying to make a line chart with ReportLab. 
I would like the declared values to be drawn from the beginning of the "section" they are part of. 
Let me explain more in the picture I attach below: in the picture the two lines start from 0, but the graph actually places them in the middle of January (blue circle) for me when I actually want it where the 0 is (red circle).

I attach below my code:

```
from reportlab.graphics.charts.linecharts import HorizontalLineChart
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF

drawing = Drawing(400, 200)

data = [
    (0, 5, 20, 22, 37, 45, 19, 4),
    (0, 20, 46, 38, 23, 21, 6, 14)
]

lc = HorizontalLineChart()
lc.x = 50
lc.y = 50
lc.height = 125
lc.width = 300
lc.data = data
lc.joinedLines = 1
names = 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug'.split(' ')
lc.categoryAxis.categoryNames = names
lc.categoryAxis.labels.boxAnchor = 'n'
lc.valueAxis.valueMin = 0
lc.valueAxis.valueMax = 60
lc.valueAxis.valueStep = 15
lc.lines[0].strokeWidth = 2
lc.lines[1].strokeWidth = 1.5
drawing.add(lc)

my_path='my_pdf.pdf'

renderPDF.drawToFile(drawing, my_path, '')
```

[image]

Comment: this looks like a bar chart with the bar top centers connected with lines

Comment: Seems to me like you shouldn't be using categories, but rather labels. Try and see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8086312/17200348) can resolve it.

Comment: Thank you all for the support, but I finally solved it myself by analyzing the standard HorizontalLineChart class.
Basically if on the lc object you set 1 to the attribute "useAbsolute" automatically the value is placed at the beginning of its "section".